# Html cannot load javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sorry about the fact that I'm a newbie, if the question is not clear, please notify me again, I will add information.
I have a sample code , but it cannot load js. Can someone tell me how to solve?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="/js/signalr.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/Cnn.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Qoo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**the error:**

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

[image]

[image]

And I have try this way,but it still cannot work

```
<script src="/wwwroot/js/signalr.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="~/js/signalr.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try: `./js/signalr.js`

Comment: Open your dev tools and check the network tab. What is the complete URL these files are fetched from? Can you open them on this URL? If no, then find out where the files are really stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on where the HTML file is, relative to the JS file.

If the index file is in the root of that folder and the JS in a sub-folder, the correct code would be:

```
<script src="js/signalr.js"></script>
```

The above code uses a relative URL as does your code however, your code is relative to the root directory and my example is relative to your current working directory.

If your URL in the browser has a driver letter at the start of it, then the JS would be loaded from a JS sub-folder in the root of that drive. For example, if the URL is `C:\wwwroot\index.html` then the browser would attempt to load the JS file from `C:\js\signalr.js` rather than `C:\wwwroot\js\signalr.js`, where the latter is the correct location.

Comment: The last part of your answer is incorrect

Comment: What is incorrect about the first part?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense, you are giving false information in the last part. If you really wanted to use absolute paths to the filesystem, which is bad practice anyway, you'd need to prepend the path with `file:///`

Comment: But if you right-click the index file and open in Chrome, it will open with the full filesystem path without the `file://` protocol.

Comment: Well, test it out on firefox, this is definitely not crossbrowser